# Develop a VSCode theme using variables

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a VScode theme.

My project structure is very simple:

```
mytheme
 |_ .vscode
   |_ launch.json
 |_ assets
   |_ ...some png files
 |_ themes
   |_ mytheme.json
 .vscodeignore
 package.json
 README.md
```

The `mytheme.json` is something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "mytheme",
    "type": "dark",
    "colors": {
        //////////////////////////////
        // CONTRAST COLOR 
        // The contrast colors are typically only set for high contrast themes. 
        // If set, they add an additional border around items across the UI to increase the contrast.
        //////////////////////////////
        // An extra border around active elements to separate them from others for greater contrast.
        "contrastActiveBorder": "#fa0000",
        // "contrastActiveBorder": "#FFFFFF00",
        // An extra border around elements to separate them from others for greater contrast.
        //"contrastBorder": "#fa0000",

        //////////////////////////////
        // BASE COLORS 
        //////////////////////////////
        // Overall border color for focused elements. This color is only used if not overridden by a component.
        "focusBorder": "#9B6DFF66",
        // Overall foreground color. This color is only used if not overridden by a component.
        "foreground": "#D9E0E8",
        // Shadow color of widgets such as Find/Replace inside the editor.
        "widget.shadow": "#1F2330",
        // Background color of text selections in the workbench (for input fields or text areas, does not apply to selections within the editor and the terminal).
        "selection.background": "#9B6DFF99",
        // Foreground color for description text providing additional information, for example for a label.
        "descriptionForeground": "#808182",
        // Overall foreground color for error messages (this color is only used if not overridden by a component).
        "errorForeground": "#9B6DFF",
        // The default color for icons in the workbench.
        "icon.foreground": "#D9E0E8",
        ...
    }
}
```

and my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "mytheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "publisher": "...",
  "icon": "assets/logo_square.png",
  "galleryBanner": {
    "color": "#1F2330",
    "theme": "dark"
  },
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.42.0"
  },
  "displayName": "Mytheme",
  "description": "...",
  "categories": [
    "Themes"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "themes": [
      {
        "label": "Mytheme",
        "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
        "path": "./themes/mytheme.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "URL": "....git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "URL": "..."
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "...",
    "email": "...",
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "vscode",
    "theme",
    "color-theme",
    "dark"
  ],
  "private": false
}
```

Very simple. It works like a charm. But there is a big problem: it's very difficult to maintain because `mytheme.json` is a very very long file and it's a simple .json and If I want to modify for example the accent color, I need to do a find and replace.

I would like to develop my theme in a smarter way, I would like to use variables, save my N colors in variables and use them.
json format doesn't support variables so I ask you how can I do that?
I don't know if there is a standard way to do that, I imagine developing in js and then running a script that transforms my work into a valid json but how?

For example:

```js
const PURPLE = "#9B6DFF"

const baseColors = {
   ...
   errorForeground: PURPLE,
   ...
}

return ...
```

I didn't find a guide to follow.

---

Following the suggestion of @rioV8, I created these files:

`.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Extension",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": [
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
      ],
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "parseToJson",
    },
  ],
}
```

`.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "parseToJson",
      "command": "tsc",
      "type": "shell",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent", 
        "panel": "new" 
      },
      "args": [
        "--target",
        "ES5",
        "--outDir",
        "js",
        "--sourceMap",
        "--watch",
        "parse.ts"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
    }
  ]
}
```

`.vscode/parse.ts`:

```
const PURPLE = "#9B6DFF"

const baseColors = {
   errorForeground: PURPLE,
}

// create json 
const mytheme = {
    "name": "mytheme",
    "type": "dark",
    "colors": {...baseColors}
}
  
function createJsonTheme() {
  // save to json
  const file = new File(mytheme, "../themes/mytheme.json", {
    type: "text/plain",
  });
}

createJsonTheme()
```

When I run it, I get:

> error TS6053: File 'parse.ts' not found.   The file is in the program
> because:
> Root file specified for compilation

The path seems ok to me, where is The problem?
The `createJsonTheme` function goal is to create an object to save then in a json file inside `themes` folder.

Comment: write a 'compiler' that transforms you JSON-variable file to a JSON-plain file and call that as a build task of the launch config you use. With the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) you can pass strings from launch to task with the `remember` command

Comment: @rioV8 Have you examples? I didn't know how to start honestly...

Comment: add an additional color lookup table to the json (remove this in the output), traverse the json and replace where colors are allowed and names used from LUT.

Comment: @rioV8 mmm ok, so like a script that loop on the json and replace variables name with variables values and create the new json?
How can I do this automatically? I would like anytime I save the theme and I'm in debugger mode, this script is called

Comment: add a pre-build task property to the launch config, and define a task that calls a shell command to transform your file

Comment: @rioV8 I edited my main message adding some information. If you could help me, i would be very grateful

Comment: watch out that the script does not overwrite your source file, name the source file `mytheme-colors.json`, if you want to compile `.ts` files don't place them in the `.vscode` folder, you have to compile the script once maybe with an npm script and run it as a node application, there is no need for the `"outFiles"` in your `launch.json` (the extension only contains the theme json file. The conversion script has to read the `mytheme-colors.json` file, parse the JSON, traverse the JSON object and replace the colors and write to `mytheme.json`

Comment: @rioV8 I prefer to create all the theme using Typescript, I think it's more easy than use a json with variables so there is no "source file", only the parse file to execute

Comment: now you have the problem that you have to compile and then run the Typescript file each try of the theme, write the script in JavaScript and you don't need to compile. the script is very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved doing like this:

`launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Run Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": [
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
      ],
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: build"
    },
    {
      "name": "Run Extension Without Build",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": [
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "npm: start",
      "detail": "nodemon --watch src src/index.js"
    },
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "build",
      "group": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "label": "npm: build",
      "detail": "node src/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch src src/index.js",
    "build": "node src/index.js && mkdir -p build",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build && vsce publish"
}
...
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises
const getTheme = require('./theme')

const ohlalaTheme = getTheme({
  theme: 'dark',
  name: 'Mytheme',
})

// write theme
fs.mkdir('./themes', { recursive: true })
  .then(() =>
    Promise.all([
      fs.writeFile('./themes/mytheme.json', JSON.stringify(ohlalaTheme, null, 2)),
    ])
  )
  .catch(() => process.exit(1))
```

`src/theme.js`

```js
const { colors } = require('./colors')

function getTheme({ theme, name }) {
  const themes = (options) => options[theme] 

  return {
    name: name,
    colors: {
      focusBorder: colors.green,
    },
    semanticHighlighting: true,
    ...
  }
}

module.exports = getTheme
```

`src/colors.js`:

```js
const colors = {
  green: '#......',
}

module.exports = { colors }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables won't help. The theme file is a mapping of token values to color values. A theme editor tool could help you to be more productive, but I don't know any.